# Future builder returns null although my list is not empty

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I have this future builder which loads a list of movies in my provider class. Whenever I reload my screen, the movies do not get returned. Below is the future builder

```
FutureBuilder(
                    future: movieData.getTrendingMovies(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Swiper(
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, i) {
                            return ChangeNotifierProvider(
                              create: (context) => Movie(),
                              child: MovieContainer(
                                imageUrl: movieData.movies[i].imageUrl,
                                id: movieData.movies[i].id,
                                rate: movieData.movies[i].rate,
                                title: movieData.movies[i].title,
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          itemCount: movieData.movies.length,
                          viewportFraction: 0.25,
                          scale: 0.4,
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Text(snapshot.error.toString()); // it returns null on the screen
                      }
                    }),
```

Also in my homescreen where I display my movies, after the build method, I create a listener(**moviesData**) to listen to all changes in the movies provider.

```
final movieData = Provider.of<Movies>(context, listen: false);
```

Below is also the methos which fetches the movies from a restfulAPI using http get request

```
Future<void> getTrendingMovies() async {
    List<String> movieTitles = [];
    List<String> movieImageUrls = [];
    List<String> movieDescriptions = [];
    List<String> movieReleaseDates = [];
    List<String> movieRates = [];
    List<String> movieIds = [];
    const _apiKey = '******************************';
    const url =
        'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/week?api_key=$_apiKey';
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
        print(response.statusCode);
        return;
      }
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body);
      List moviesList = extractedData['results'] as List;
      List<Movie> loadedMovies = [];
      for (int i = 0; i < moviesList.length; i++) {
        String movieTitle = moviesList[i]['original_title'] ?? '';
        String? movieImage =
            'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400${moviesList[i]['poster_path']}'; //results[0].poster_path
        String movieDescription =
            moviesList[i]['overview'] ?? ''; //results[0].overview
        String movieReleaseDate = moviesList[i]['release_date'] ?? '';
        String? movieRate = moviesList[i]['vote_average'].toString();
        String? movieId = moviesList[i]['id'].toString();
        movieTitles.add(movieTitle);
        movieImageUrls.add(movieImage);
        movieDescriptions.add(movieDescription);
        movieReleaseDates.add(movieReleaseDate);
        movieRates.add(movieRate);
        movieIds.add(movieId);
        loadedMovies.add(
          Movie(
            id: movieIds[i],
            title: movieTitles[i],
            imageUrl: movieImageUrls[i],
            description: movieDescriptions[i],
            rate: double.parse(movieRates[i]),
            releaseDate: movieReleaseDates[i],
          ),
        );
      }
      _movies = loadedMovies;
      notifyListeners();
      //print(_movies.last.title); //This prints the name of the last movie perfectly....This gets called unlimited times whenever I set the listen of the **moviesData** to true
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things to unpack here.

1. Instead of a ChangeNotifierProvider, I believe you should use a `Consumer` widget that listens to your `Movies` provided service when you call the `notifyListeners` call, so make it `Consumer<Movie>`.
2. You can still call it using the `Provider.of` above for the sake of making the async call via the `FutureBuilder`, but I believe because you're not returning anything out of the `getTrendingMovies` and is just a `Future<void>` and you're querying the `snapshot.hasData`, well there is no data coming through the snapshot. Maybe instead you should call `snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done` as opposed to querying for whether it has data.
3. Make sure that the `response.body` is truly returning a JSON value, but I believe your issue is in one of the points above.